# Find elements of a vector in a list and collect information in data frame

Tags: r, list

From a vector with gene ids, I want to identify which sublist contains one or more of the ids and the associated pvalue.
The result should be a list of data frames with a col for each gene ID, a second col indicating if the ID appears as boolean and a third col with the pval of that gene ID)

Thanks to Pauls question i realized that a gene ID might be in several sublists and the pvalue would indicate its specificity. Accordingly, the expected result should be a list for a df for each sublist and a boolean vector indicating if the geneID is present. Sorry for the edit.

## example data

```
   the_list <- list(
  a = data.frame(ids = c("ABB", 'SDG', 'SHD', 'DUR'), pval = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05)),
  b = data.frame(ids =c('DYR' ,'LRH' ,'FPR', 'FUR', 'DCTWE', 'IRN', 'DRB'), pval = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 4, 5, 6)),
  c = data.frame(ids =c('SYR' ,'SDT', 'DFN' ,'FRQ' ,'DFRR', 'SDR'), pval = c(0.01, 0.03, 0.05, 0.05, 5, 2))
)

the_vector <- c("ABB", 'FUR', 'DFN')




 expected_result <- list(
  'a' = data.frame(
    gene_ids = c("ABB", 'FUR', 'DFN'),
    in_list = c(T, F, F),
    pval = c(0.01, NA, NA)),
  'b' = data.frame(
    gene_ids = c("ABB", 'FUR', 'DFN'),
    in_list = c(F, T, F),
    pval = c(NA, 0.05, NA)),
  'c' = data.frame(
    gene_ids = c("ABB", 'FUR', 'DFN'),
    in_list = c(F, F, T),
    pval = c(NA,  NA, 0.05))
  )
```

Comment: Is it certain that a gene ID will only occur in one of the lists?  Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks for asking! The gene IDs can be in several lists (the pvalue would determine if the association is specific or not. Accordingly, the expected result whould be able to contain multiple answers, I will edit the question accordingly. I tried  several approaches from SO [vapply(l, function(x) sum(is.element(x,v)) or sapply(L1, function(x) which(x %in% v1)) 0) but could not get the desired result.

Comment: Wait your list is a list of dataframes now? Please don't change the question that drastically, it makes old answers obsolete.

Comment: Please see this post on meta for guidance on altering questions.: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266141/4676560

Comment: Thank you, next time I will start a new question when a larger edit is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Base R solution:

```
# For each list element: 
# res_list => list of data.frames
res_list <- lapply(
  the_list,
  function(x){
    # Resolve the index of the matched elements: 
    # idx => integer vector
    idx <- match(the_vector, x$ids)
    # Resolve the required data.frame: 
    # data.frame => env
    data.frame(
      gene_ids = the_vector, 
      in_list = !(is.na(idx)),
      p_val = x$pval[idx],
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
      row.names = NULL
    )
  }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Loop through the list of data.frames and merge:

```
lapply(the_list, function(i){
  res <- merge(data.frame(ids = the_vector), i, all.x = TRUE)
  res$in_list <- !is.na(res$pval)
  res
  })
# $a
#   ids pval in_list
# 1 ABB 0.01    TRUE
# 2 DFN   NA   FALSE
# 3 FUR   NA   FALSE
# 
# $b
#   ids pval in_list
# 1 ABB   NA   FALSE
# 2 DFN   NA   FALSE
# 3 FUR 0.05    TRUE
# 
# $c
#   ids pval in_list
# 1 ABB   NA   FALSE
# 2 DFN 0.05    TRUE
# 3 FUR   NA   FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dplyr::bind_rows(the_list, .id = "in_list") %>%
  filter(ids %in% the_vector)
```

gives

```
  in_list ids pval
1       a ABB 0.01
2       b FUR 0.05
3       c DFN 0.05
```

Edit - works with multi matches too - will give a row per match, even if the same id has previously matched - you can then order by `in_list` or `ids` as appropriate.

This no longer conforms to the desired output since the question was edited, but I will leave it here as it's simple and contains the same information.